# Left Join not returning all rows in left table

Tags: mysql

I have a film database, one of the tables is 'categories' which holds all of the genres a movie in the database could have.

Running the following query:

```
SELECT category.name FROM category
```

Gives back the rows:

```
Action
Animation
Children
Classics
Comedy
Documentary
Drama
Family
Foreign
Games
Horror
Music
New
Sci-Fi
Sports
Travel
```

I am trying to query the database to find the # of each particular genre a specific actor has a role in, but I want it to return ALL of the genres with the # in the next column. This was my initial query:

```
SELECT q1.name AS 'Film Category', COUNT(q2.name) AS '# of Films Ed Chase has appeared in' 
FROM (
    SELECT category.name FROM category 
) AS q1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT category.name FROM category 
    INNER JOIN film_category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
    INNER JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
    INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
    INNER JOIN actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
    WHERE actor.first_name = 'ED' AND actor.last_name = 'CHASE'
) AS q2
ON q1.name = q2.name AND '# of Films Ed Chase has starred in' >= 0
GROUP BY q2.name
ORDER BY q2.name;
```

And it gives back this table, missing some of the rows (I want it to give all the genres, not just the one's that the actor had a role in):

```
Film Category   # of Films Ed Chase has appeared in
Animation       0
Action          2
Classics        2
Documentary     6
Drama           3
Foreign         2
Music           1
New             2
Sci-Fi          1
Sports          2
Travel          1
```

Interestingly it returned '0' for 'Animation' but no rows for 'Children' or 'Comedy' which is the result I was looking for (all genres returned).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your inner join is making me crosseyed, so it's probably not doing what you want. Give me a few minutes to try rewriting it.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the actor's name is always in upper case?

Comment: Also, your inner join doesn't need to reference `film` if there's a 1-1 mapping between `film_category.film_id` and `film_actor.film_id`.

Comment: Is a category the same as a genre?

Comment: Consider providing CREATE and INSERT statements, and a desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT()` doesn't count NULLs, and your left join puts NULLs in the records where there isn't a value in the right-hand table. Your outer join actually is (or should be - check this) returning all the desired rows, but the outer select with the aggregate function is eating them.

Try moving your `count()` into the right-hand subquery, and then in your outer query replace it with `IFNULL(q2.count, '0')` to replace NULLs with zeros.

I will note that you should be grouping on q1.name, not q2.name.

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't an answer. It explains why he didn't get the results he wanted (except for that one '0' that he did get) and suggests a change to the query that would give the desired result.

Comment: No rows were returned for children or comedy. There's nothing here that's going to fix that.

Comment: A left outer join between the two subqueries will return rows `children | (NULL)` and `comedy | (NULL)`. The call to `IFNULL` in the outermost query will replace those nulls with zeros.

Comment: It will have no impact on what rows are returned.

Comment: Replacing nulls with 0s will make no difference to the number of rows returned. If children and comedy were missing in the original query, they will still be missing in your query too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94475/discussion-between-darwin-von-corax-and-strawberry).

Comment: No. Set up an example and test it for yourself.